# Can the <header> tag be contained within the <aside> tag in HTML5?

Tags: html, header, semantics

I'm wondering if this construction would be semantically correct in HTML5.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <aside>
        <header>
            <h1></h1>
        </header>
        <div>

        </div>
    </aside>
    <section id="content">

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is a left bar taking the 30% of the screen, with the logo and some stuff below it, and then the content taking the other 70% on the right side.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong per se with the code you’ve put there, but bear in mind that the `<aside>` tag is [a sectioning content element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/content-models.html#sectioning-content-0), so the `<header>` and `<h1>` inside it will be treated as the heading just for the `<aside>`, rather than for the whole page (at least under the HTML5 outlining algorithm, which, [sadly, seems to be dead in practice](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2013/10/html5-document-outline/)).

That might be what you intend. If not, then if everything in the left column is pretty much just introductory content for the page, you could put it all inside a [`<header>` element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-header-element.html#the-header-element) and lose the `<aside>` completely:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1></h1>
        <div>

        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="content">

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

You might also consider replacing `<section id="content"></section>` with [a `<main>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main).

Comment: This is interesting, because of course, I want `<header>` to be the heading of the whole page. But at the same time I want to have it in a left column whit more content, which in this case is **Google Maps Directions**. So probably is better just to wrap the `<header>` and the `<div id="directions">` within another `<div>` and not within `<aside>`. What do you think?

Comment: @Pugicerber: yup, that sounds like a good idea. As I said, if you think the Google Maps Directions are introductory content for the page (which is obviously a subjective decision), they can happily live inside the `<header>` tag along with your `<h1>`. But if not, a `<div>` is the way to go to achieve the styling you want.

Answer (score 16):

Given that HTML5 is still a draft, the specs says

> A header element is intended to
>   usually contain the section's heading
>   (an h1–h6 element or an hgroup
>   element), but this is not required.
>   The header element can also be used to
>   wrap a section's table of contents, a
>   search form, or any relevant logos.

and

> The [aside] element can be used for
>   typographical effects like pull quotes
>   or sidebars, for advertising, for
>   groups of nav elements, and for other
>   content that is considered separate
>   from the main content of the page.

and the only "restriction" on the `<aside />` tag is

> It's not appropriate to use the aside
>   element just for parentheticals, since
>   those are part of the main flow of the
>   document

event though there are no explicit examples with `<header />` tags inside `<aside />` tags, I would consider them OK.

Links:

1. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-header-element
2. http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-aside-element

Comment: If the header in the aside is meant to be a header for the page though (instead of just for the aside element), then it shouldn’t be in the aside.

Comment: Hey @Albireo, what do you think of @paul-d-waite answer?

Comment: @Puigcerber: He's right, it depends on what you want to do, if your header - as you're saying - refers to the whole page, you shouldn't put it in a `<aside />`.

Comment: Thanks to both for your answers.